# Meaning of "the terms will be offset"

Tags: meaning

What does "offset" mean here?
When I ask Chat GTP about the meaning, it says " "offset" means that the terms of the chair and co-chair will be intentionally staggered or adjusted in a way that they do not occur simultaneously or directly follow each other."
Is this correct?

> The role of the vice chair(s) shall be to support the chair in the previously mentioned roles, cover for the chair in their absence, and lead the process to select a new chair. Chair and co-chair terms will be offset if possible.

Comment: The idea is that you won't have a chair and vice chairs starting on the same date and finishing on the same date. That would be undesirable because both would be new in the role and neither would have experience helpful to the other.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you

Comment: And for practical purposes, one term is made longer the first time, so that even if they begin at the same time, one goes longer than the other to create the offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Offset" in this case refers to a period of time in a position. In other words, the terms in the position will be "staggered" or offset from each other, so they don't start and end at the same time.

Comment: Yes, people are elected or appointed for a term.